# Resize event does not trigger in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-easyui

There are more than one iframes and those iframe all will execute a piece of code below

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('#dg').datagrid('resize', {
        width: $(window).parents().width(),
        height: $(window).parents().height() - h
    }).datagrid('resize', {
        width: $(window).parents().width(),
        height: $(window).parents().height() - h
    });
});
```

It register a resize event, but only the iframe which has executed the code first will trigger the resize event while i am adjusting the browser size, the others doesn't trigger the resize event. And when i execute the code below

```
$(window).trigger("resize")
```

all the iframes will trigger the resize event, why?

Comment: First of all, your selector `$('#dg')` is an id selector, and will apply to the first element that matches, even if you have multiple instances with the same id. Then, I'd also like to know where this script is located: in the individual iframes, or the document? You could do a quick JSFiddle to demonstrate. A reference to the datagrid plugin documentation will also help understand the problem better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The script is located in the individual iframes. I have trailled and I found if I change the browser's width, the resize event will be triggered in all of the iframes, but if I change the borwser's height, it will only be triggered in the first iframe.

Comment: I find that to be a very unlikely scenario, because any window height/width change triggers the same 'resize' event, and I don't see why it should behave differently in each scenario, unless your resize handler is doing something funny, like `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` somewhere.

where is this `h` coming from in the code below?
`height: $(window).parents().height() - h`